# Fetch values from api and display in reactjs app piechart

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, api

I made API from where I am returning values and now am trying to take fetch those values and display in pie chart using reactjs but am not able to fetch.

```
class Graph extends Component {
    ComponentWillMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3010/analysis')
        .then(response{response.json()})
        .then(data => console.log(response))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ReactFC
        {...pieConfigs}/>
            );
    }
}

export default Graph;
```

This is my code. Can anyone please tell me what are the changes I need to make to  be able to display pie chart in react app?

Comment: If you want how to configure chart - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fusioncharts

Comment: Also make you API call in `componentDidMount` and instead of `console.log` set the data to state which can be used for chart configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
class Graph extends Component {
    state = { pieConfigs }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('http://localhost:3010/analysis')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data }))
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ReactFC {...this.state.pieConfigs}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Explanation:
1. Fetching data from componentDidMount, not componentWillMount. You can see [this article](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/) as reference.
2. Use state/props for data related to ui. You can use state and setState to update the data and pass it as props to ReactFC. Updating state or props will trigger re-render, so that the ui will be up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you fetch API right after component unmount, try

```
ComponentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3010/analysis')
    .then(response{response.json()})
    .then(data => console.log(response))
}
```